# Onto (surjective) functions of 2 variables

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I have a couple of functions I'm curious about:

> $f(m,n)=m^2 -n^2$ and $f(m,n)=|m|-|n| $, for $m,n\in \mathbb{Z} $. The codomain also consists of all integers.

My understanding is that for this to be as surjective function, every element of the codomain should map to some element in the domain. Perhaps it is easier to find a case where it doesn't if I want to prove they are not surjective? How would I go about a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the codomain? If you don't specify it, the question makes no sense.

Comment: The codomain is also an element of all integers.

Comment: You should edit your question to include the information about the codomain.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: $$m^2-n^2=2$$ has no integer solution.

As for the second function, note that $$x=|x|-|0|$$ if $x \ge 0$ and $$x=|0|-|x|$$ otherwise.

Comment: Oh I like that! So there will be gaps in there. That helps for sure.